# How can I actually get to the AKLT state from a product state in finite depth?

Tags: symmetry, quantum-entanglement, topological-order, spin-models, spin-chains

I'm currently learning about symmetry-protected topological phases in one dimension. The ground state of the AKLT model provides one such example. In particular, the AKLT state for any length $L$ *cannot* be approximated to a fixed error $\epsilon$ with a local quantum circuit of depth independent of $L$ when the unitary gates respect appropriate symmetries. Here, the error is measured in terms of expectation values of local observables, and the unitary circuit is acting on a product state. The circuits I'm imagining in my head are brickwork circuits. By AKLT state, I'm referring to the unique ground state of the AKLT chain with periodic boundary conditions.

---

However, from what I've read, the AKLT state *can* be approximated with a finite-depth circuit acting on a product state when the unitary gates don't obey symmetries.

Could one perfectly reach the AKLT state of length $L$ with such a family of finite-depth circuits? By that, I mean whether for each $L$ there exists some finite depth local circuit $U$ (depth independent of $L$) where $\langle \text{AKLT}| U|\text{product}\rangle = 1$. Here $|\text{product}\rangle$ is some product state, like the fully-polarized state $|++++...+\rangle$.

---

Here is some background. The Affleck-Kennedy-Lieb-Tasaki (AKLT) model is a quantum chaotic spin-1 chain that nevertheless has an exactly solvable ground state for all $L$. This exactly solvable ground state is an example of a symmetry protected topological (SPT) state. From what I gather, SPT states are short-range entangled, which means that they can be (approximately) disentangled to a product state with a local quantum circuit with depth independent of $L$.

What sets SPT states apart from other short-range entangled states is that if the local unitaries are constrained to be symmetric under appropriate symmetries, one can't find a local circuit with depth independent of $L$ to disentangle the state. This is only tangential to my problem at hand; it means that the short-depth circuit will necessarily have unitaries breaking the invariance under $\pi$ rotations of at least two of the $x,y,z$ axes.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: If you only want an example of how to go with non-symmetric circuits from a trivial to an SPT state - *not* necessarily the AKLT state - the answer becomes "it is possible", if you go to a zero-correlation length state (e.g. the "AKLT without the projector", i.e. singlets between adjacent sites, with local Hilbert space 1/2 $\times$ 1/2 = 0$\oplus$1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not get to the AKLT state exactly from a product state with a finite-depth circuit. The reason is that AKLT has a finite correlation length, while any state obtained from a product state with finite-depth circuit (regardless of symmetry) must have zero correlation length.

Update: in fact, one can prove that in a chain of spin-1's, there does not exist a globally SO(3) symmetric finite-depth circuit that maps a trivial phase to a SPT phase.

Comment: +1 This is an interesting answer to read. I want to give a friendly challenge to it: on page 47 of a [PhD thesis](https://www.stonybrook.edu/commcms/grad-physics-astronomy/_theses/prakash-abhishodh-august-2018.pdf) asks the question "How much symmetry needs to be broken to be able to map the ground
state of a non-trivial SPT phase to a product state using an FDUC [Finite Depth Unitary Circuit]?" and claims that for AKLT, breaking $Z_2 \times Z_2$ to $Z_2$ suffices. Page 49 gives an explicit symmetry breaking for an AKLT-like model, but I can't convert it to the full AKLT chain.

Comment: Another friendly challenge - "SPT phases are also called states with short-range entanglement or short-range entangled (SRE) states. To be more precise, SRE states are states that can be transformed, by applying a finite-depth local unitary quantum circuit, into a product state." This is from page 53 of Chiu et al.'s [review article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.03535.pdf). If the AKLT state is an SPT state, it's an SRE state that by definition can be transformed with a finite-depth local unitary circuit into a product state. How do you reconcile this with your answer?

Comment: For your second question, this is a well-known defect of the proposal (that SPT can be transformed by FDLUC to a product state), for the same reason. We either have to allow errors, or replace FDLUC with locally generated unitary.

Comment: The explicit symmetry breaking transformation on 49 is from a product state to a product state.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I agree with your second comment about product state to product state. For the correlation length, is it that there are only correlations between operators separated no more than $d$ apart in physical space for a product state produced with depth $d$ unitary circuit? Also, in my question I ask about both an approximation and a perfect reaching of the AKLT state; your question definitively answers the latter negatively. Do you know whether an explicit approximating circuit has been discovered?

Comment: @user196574 Regarding the "approximating circuit", you have to be more concrete: What is your figure of merit? E.g., do you want to fix the depth & locality of the circuit, and want to find the best approximation? (Note that all approximations will get worse exponentially in the system size, so you might want to maximize the length scale $\zeta$ of this decay.) -- Constructing *some* approximation is likely trivial: Just not doing anything to a suitable product state will likely give a non-zero overlap with the target state.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks, those are good points. I would likely want the projector onto spin-$2$ on any pair of adjacent sites to be small relative to $1$, like $.05$. Shrinking fidelity with system size is OK so long as I can have a fixed depth and locality of the circuit yielding a state with the projector constraint above. To me, I would say then that such a state "locally" (probably just on $2$ sites) looks very similar to the AKLT state.

Comment: @user196574 Do you mind updating your question accordingly? (Or, better, post a new question: As it is now, it does *not* ask about approximations, and adding that would render Meng Cheng's answer if not invalid, then incomplete.

Comment: Indeed if the question is about approximation, then it probably very strongly depends on what the merit and I can imagine has to be answered by some optimization.

Comment: @MengCheng Naively, it is not even clear whether the optimal state is in the right phase. -- Regarding your edit about globally SO(3) symmetric circuits: Can this be understood from the existence of fractionalized edge modes? (BTW, do local circuits which locally are not SO(3)-invariant but globally are even exist?)

Comment: @NobertSchurt yes, indeed we would like the state to be in the right phase, so maybe have to search in the right parameter space (ideally). The simplest argument for the non-existence of such symmetric circuit is indeed to look at the edge modes, which must be even dimensional since they are projective reps of SO(3), but can not happen because we assume there is only spin-1 in the system.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch For the second question, one can definitely write down matrix product unitaries that are not locally SO(3), but globally are. But you are right, for spin-1 no such circuits exist regardless of whether it changes the SPT index or not, so the statement is bit vacuous...

Comment: *one can definitely write down matrix product unitaries that are not locally SO(3)* -- without cheating, i.e. in a way where it is *impossible* to write it with local SO(3)-invariant operations? (Otherwise one can always insert random 1-qubit gates.)

Comment: @NobertSchuch I'm using the result in your paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.09183: as in equation 2, if the virtual bonds transform as different SO(3) reps then the physical ones, then I think it's impossible to write it with local SO(3)-invariant gates.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch One thing I should clarify is that my original question asked about both exact constructions and approximations (and I commented on Meng Cheng's answer given that), but because I realized that Meng Cheng's answer firmly answered the existence of exact constructions in the negative, and that approximations was probably another can of worms, I edited my question to remove the approximations part so that I could accept Meng Cheng's answer. I'll probably post a separate question on approximations once I've clarified some things in my head.